# Objects are not considered the same in Dictionary keys - but __eq__ is implemented

Tags: python, dictionary

The following code gives an error message:

```
    class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, test = 0):
        self.test = test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Test(1)
    t2 = Test(2)
    t3 = Test(3)
    t4 = Test(1)
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict[t1] = 1
    my_dict[t2] = 2
    my_dict[t3] = 3

    print(my_dict[t4])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexander\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PipeProcessTest
\PipeProcessTest\DictionaryKeys.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(my_dict[t4])
KeyError: <__main__.Test object at 0x0000000002F18080>
```

This is due to the fact that python is treating t1 and t4 as different objects. However, when I implement the comparison operator '**eq**', with the following code:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.test == other.test:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I get another error message, "unhashable type: 'Test'" telling me that now the dictionary cannot hash the Test object. How can I fix this problem, so that Python can recognize t1 and t4 as being the same, but also being able to hash the Test object?

Comment: You know you never actually put `t4` in your dict, right?

Comment: @MorganThrapp, I think that is the question, how to make doing a lookup with `t4`  to return t1 as they are both  initialised with `1`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ahhh, that makes slightly more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. This is due to the fact that python is treating t1 and t4 as different objects. However, when I implement the comparison operator 'eq', with the following code:**

When you do this below operation in python....

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, test = 0):
        self.test = test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Test(1)
    t2 = Test(2)
    t3 = Test(3)
    t4 = Test(1)
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict[t1] = 1
    my_dict[t2] = 2
    my_dict[t3] = 3
```

This means that you are actually trying to create a `dict` with keys as `Test` objects, Python does first checks whether the `keys` are `hashable` or not.

Any `object` in Python is `hashable` when it returns any `integer` value for `obj.__hash__()` method. In python all user defined classes by default gets some hash value that is `id(self)`.

Obviously when you get `id` value as it's `hash` value, they are gonna look some thing like this value `8772302607193`. SO with these id's if we construct the `hash` table it might looks like this..

Lets assume id's like this..

```
id(t1) = 1
id(t2) = 4   # These are just assumptions.
id(t3) = 10  # actual id's are long values.
id(t4) = 20
```

This is how `hash` table gets constructed....

```
    hash     Actual
    value    value  
    ------------------
    | 1    |  t1     |
    ------------------
    | 2    | NULL    |
    ------------------   # Consider that you've respective values are
    | 3    | NULL    |   # here, just for representation I've mentioned
    ------------------   # t1, t2, t3, t4, ..
    | 4    | t2      |
    ------------------
           |
           |
    ------------------
    | 10   |  t3     |
    ------------------
           |
         SO ON
```

Like this your `hash` table gets constructed, So here when you try for getting value of `t4` just trying `my_dict[t4]`. First python check for `hash` value of `t4` by calling `t4.__hash__()`, as per the assumption `t4` hash value is `20`.

After getting the hash value `20` it checks over the hash table with index as 20, since we didn't insert any value with `20` Python simply raises `KeyError` exception, this is the reason your were getting `KeyError` when you try `my_dict[t4]`.

**Another Scenario Here:**

If you try overriding `__hash__` method f `Test` class and proceed with the same operations you did like below..

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, test = 0):
        self.test = test
    def __hash__(self):
        self.test       # You are just returning the same value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Test(1)
    t2 = Test(2)
    t3 = Test(3)
    t4 = Test(1)
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict[t1] = 1
    my_dict[t2] = 2
    my_dict[t3] = 3
```

Since we've `overloaded` hash method to return the same value as initialized, below are the hash values we get

```
t1 = 1 , t2 = 2, t3 = 3, t4 = 1
```

This is how `hash` table looks like when we've multiple values with `same hash value`.

```
      hash    Actual
      value   value  
      ------------------
      | 1    | [t1,t4] | # List of values for the same hash value.
      ------------------
      | 2    |  t2     |
      ------------------ # Consider that you've respective values are
      | 3    |  t3     | # here, just for representation I've mentioned
      ------------------ # t1, t2, ...
      | 4    |  NULL   |
      ------------------
           |
         SO ON
```

In this situation when you try to get `my_dict[t4]`, as said before first checks for the hash value `t4.__hash__()` returns `1`. Now Python dict check at `index` 1 in the `hash table` and it gets multiple values `[t1, t4]`.

And this is the situation where `__eq__` helps you to identify the object when you've multiple values with same `hash value`. You can do like below to avoid that situation...

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, test = 0):
        self.test = test
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.test
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self is other
```

In your case you just need to verify the `self.test` value to get the object...

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, test = 0):
        self.test = test
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.test
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other.test == self.test
```

This is how you can manage your dict values!

Answer (score 9):

You need to implement `__hash__` in addition to `__eq__`.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) for notes on how to do this.  The main thing to keep in mind is that objects that compare equal must have the same hash value.  So if you want to compare equality only by looking at the `test` attribute, then your `__hash__` also needs to use only the `test` attribute.  Searching for information about `__hash__` and `__eq__` will also turn up many previous questions on this site about this.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to return `self.test` in the `__hash__` method so your objects hash value is based on their test attribute so t1 and t4 will have the same hash value and a dict lookup on t1 or t4 will return the same value:

```
   def __init__(self, test = 0):
        self.test = test
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.test == other.test
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.test
```

The if/else is not needed in your `eq`, you can simply return the outcome of  `self.test == other.test`

```
In [2]: t1 = Test(1)   
In [3]: t2 = Test(2)   
In [4]: t3 = Test(3)   
In [5]: t4 = Test(1)
In [6]:  my_dict = {}    
In [7]: print(t1 == t4)
True   
In [8]: my_dict[t1] = 1    
In [9]: my_dict[t2] = 2    
In [10]: my_dict[t3] = 3
In [11]: print(my_dict[t4])
1
```

Comment: I too can't understand the downvote - your solution should work. It's actually the same thing said by BrenBarn. Perhaps it's because you did not explain the reason behind it? (just guessing).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, yep, fixed.

Comment: @Iserni, maybe so but there dv was almost instantaneous so there may be other forces at work!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone, here's a pretty decent example:

```
class NonComparable(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

# Convert a cmp= function into a key= function 
class Comparable(object): 
    def __init__(self, val, hash_lambda, cmp_lambda): 
        self.val = val
        self.hash_lambda = hash_lambda
        self.cmp_lambda = cmp_lambda

    def __hash__(self): 
        return self.hash_lambda(self.val)

    def __eq__(self, other): 
        return self.cmp_lambda(self.val, other.val) == 0
        # return id(self) == id(other)

# driver code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # __hash__ is available even if you don't implement it, it'd return hash(nc1), not id(nc1). hash() isn't available by default.
    # Note also,
    # id(123) = an integer
    # hash(456) = 456
    # So, hash(id(nc1)) = id(nc1)
    nc1 = NonComparable()
    nc1_hash = nc1.__hash__()

    nc2 = NonComparable()
    nc2_hash = nc2.__hash__() 

    moduli = 2
    hash_lambda = lambda x : x * x
    cmp_lambda_by_val = lambda x,y : x == y
    cmp_lambda_by_objid = lambda x,y : id(x) == id(y)

    c1 = Comparable(5, hash_lambda, cmp_lambda_by_val) # hash = 5*5 = 25
    c2 = Comparable(8, hash_lambda, cmp_lambda_by_val) # hash = 8*8 = 64

    # same hash code (To simulate hash collision), but compare by Equal based on id(obj)
    c3 = Comparable(5, hash_lambda, cmp_lambda_by_objid) 
    c4 = Comparable(5, hash_lambda, cmp_lambda_by_objid) 

    dict1 = {}
    dict1[nc1] = nc1
    dict1[nc2] = nc2
    res = dict1[nc1]

    dict2 = {}
    dict2[c1] = c1
    dict2[c2] = c2
    res = dict2[c1]

    dict3 = {}
    dict3[c3] = c3
    dict3[c4] = c4
    res = dict3[c3]
    # id(c3) == id(res)
    pass
```

**References**

[Objects are not considered the same in Dictionary keys - but __eq__ is implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279666/objects-are-not-considered-the-same-in-dictionary-keys-but-eq-is-implement)

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/hash

https://dbader.org/blog/python-dictionaries-maps-and-hashtables

https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/37643853